# Use variable from external file in Neovim init.vim

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, and Neovim 0.8 from the Konsole command-line.

I'm using `vim-dadbod` and `vim-dadbod-ui` plugins for MySQL database connection.

I don't want to have to type the password every time I open the connection, but I can't just use it directly in the mysql url (`mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>`) in the `init.vim` file, because this file ***WILL BE SHARED*** with other people.

Therefore, I want to store the user & password in a separate file, and call it with a variable inside my `init.vim`.

I've tried to create a `~/.config/nvim/lua/myVars.lua` file and use `require('myVars')` in my `init.vim` file, but didn't work...

So, how can I import the variables from the lua file, and use it within `init.vim`?

Comment: Why not use an environment variable + `os.getenv`?

Comment: @LMD Do you mean setting something like the "$PATH" in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that would be one example of an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could - instead of a `require`d Lua config file - opt for an environment variable which you could then access from Lua using [`os.getenv`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up setting the Environment Vars in my `~/.bashrc` to make them permanent, and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a plugin to help you manage local project items such as database or debugging tasks.

I've been helping to develop the plugin

https://github.com/kndndrj/nvim-projector

Which has built in support for dadbod configurations, nvim-dap, and even just running shell commands.

I put my database dadbod connection information in my project file stored at ./projector.json for each project I am working on.

Then just keep the file out of source control by putting a line in your .gitignore file and your all setup!